# How can I fix 'ORA-00904' error in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I'm trying to make a code in SQL server, but the server says there is 'ORA-00904' error. 
I have to show the name and city of customers who don't live in Harrison and Woodside and who have more than 500 in their accounts using SELECT.

This is ACCOUNT TABLE.

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER   BRANCH_NAME   BALANCE
         A-101      Downtown       500
         A-102    Perryridge       400
         A-201      Brighton       900
         A-215        Mianus       700
         A-217      Brighton       750
         A-222       Redwood       700
         A-305    Round Hill       350
```

This is DEPOSITOR TABLE.

```
CUSTOMER_NAME   ACCOUNT_NUMBER
        Hayes            A-102 
      Johnson            A-101
      Johnson            A-201
        Jones            A-217
      Lindsay            A-222
        Smith            A-215
       Turner            A-305
```

This is CUSTOMER TABLE.

```
CUSTOMER_NAME   CUSTOMER_STREET   CUSTOMER_CITY
        Adams            Spring      Pittsfield
       Brooks           Senator        Brooklyn
        Curry             North             Rye
        Glenn         Sand Hill        Woodside
        Green            Walnut        Stamford
        Hayes              Main        Harrison
      Johnson              Alma       Palo Alto
        Jones              Main        Harrison
      Lindsay              Park      Pittsfield
        Smith             North             Rye
       Turner            Putnam        Stamford
     Williams            Nassau       Princeton
```

I already tried the code below and I guess there is problem with alias but I don't know exactly why.

```
SELECT customer_name, 
       customer_city 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   depositor X 
                       full OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                                        FROM   customer Y 
                                        WHERE  NOT customer_city = 'Harrison' 
                                               AND NOT customer_city = 
                                                       'Woodside') 
                                    ON X.customer_name = y.customer_name) Z 
               full OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                                FROM   account W) 
                            ON Z.account_num = w.account_num) 
WHERE  balance >= 500;
```

Comment: "How can I fix ORA-00904 error in mysql?" Not possible because `ORA-00904` is not a MySQL error but a Oracle database error... Besides MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Just a guess, as I haven't used Oracle in over a decade (and even then not for long), but I'm not sure the Y alias can be referenced outside of the subquery it is created in; and that subquery has no alias to be referenced by.

Comment: `>= 500` is not the same as “over 500”, just saying

Comment: I think you should also provide expected results as text formatted data the query could be rewritten more easy i geuss like ready some answers are geussing right now..

Comment: @chloe if you can please check my answer you dont need any joins as theres no other table columns to have a join rather you just need a reference of other tables to manipulate and filter results as your final table customer is the one who needs to be the only table using other tables as lookups via subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's no need for all those subqueries with `full outer joins`.  You can just use regular `joins` and aggregate on the `sum`:

```
select c.customer_name, c.customer_city
from customer c
    join depositor d on c.customer_name = d.customer_name
    join account a on d.account_number = a.account_number
where c.customer_city not in ('Harrison','Woodside')
group by c.customer_name, c.customer_city
having sum(a.balance) > 500
```

A couple notes: I'd recommend using a `customer_id` as your `primary key` instead of `customer_name`. Duplicate names like `johnson` can cause issues and false results.  Also it looks like the `depositor` table is a `1-n` table with the `customer` table.  That's why this uses a `having` statement with `sum` instead of `where` criteria.

Comment: even a join is not needed in this case take a look at my query in the answers below

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried the code below and I guess there is problem with alias
>   but I don't know exactly why.

Correct geuss a alias is indeed missing.

```
SELECT customer_name, 
       customer_city 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   depositor X 
                       full OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                                        FROM   customer Y 
                                        WHERE  NOT customer_city = 'Harrison' 
                                               AND NOT customer_city = 
                                                       'Woodside') 
                                    ON X.customer_name = y.customer_name) Z 
               full OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                                FROM   account W) AS alias # here it was missing
               ON Z.account_num = w.account_num) AS alias # here it was missing
WHERE  balance >= 500;
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should put alias after 'Z.account_num = w. account_num) ? I tried but it says 'ORA-00933' error.

Answer (score 0):

Idk why your query is so complex with joins. Can try with the below query

```
     select c.customer_name,c.customer_city from customer c
      where 
       c.customer_city not in 
      ( 'Woodside','Harrison' )
       and c.customer_name in 
     (Select d.customer_name
       from depositor d where 
     d.account_number in
    (Select a.account_number from account a where
     a.balance >=500)
     )
```

The above query might help as its short and includes no joins

Comment: where it gives the pointer for invalid identifier which line if you can please try again with the above updated query and tell if it works if not which line it shows as invalid identifier

Comment: @chloe Looks like it's just missing a closing `parentheses`.  Although I think all these nested `in` statements might be slower than just using `join`.

Comment: it was just a `)` missing can u check now

Comment: I tried again, and It says ORA-00904 at "C"."CITY". (in the first line)

Comment: it was `customer_city` may be when i referred that might have read incorrectly from the table can try now with the above